# the set consisting of polynomials of degree n is not a vector space over R. Why

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, matrix-analysis

The set
R[x]n = { f (x) ∈ R[x] | the degree of f (x) ≤ n}
is a vector space over R under the usual addition and scalar multiplication
operations.
However, the set consisting of polynomials of degree n is not a vector
space over R. Why ?

Comment: $1x^{n}+(-1)x^{n}$ does not belong  to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its not a vector space since your space is not closed under addition:

$(x^2+x+1) + (-x^2+2x+2) = 3x+3.$

You start from polynomials of degree 2. But the sum is a polynomial of degree 1.